# Using infinispan module with wildfly 27/28

Tags: wildfly, infinispan, wildfly-27

I'm trying to upgrade an application from wildfly 26 to wildfly 27/28. The big step here is the javax to jakarta shift of course.

Today we're using embedded infinispan module version 9.4.16.Final downloaded from https://infinispan.org/download/. This of course leads to some classnotfoundexceptions because of references to javax-interfaces. Downloading the latest version 14.0.19 also leads to similar classnotfoundexceptions. This happens because the module doesn't contain the jakarta-version, i.e. `infinispan-core-14.0.19.Final.jar` instead of `infinispan-core-jakarta-14.0.19.Final.jar`.

There is also reference to a newer 15.0.0.Dev04 version of infinispan, sadly it links to a non-existing wildfly-module.

Has anybody successfully integrated embedded infinispan after wildfly 27? Is there any good guides or tips?

Answer (score 0):

There is a org.infinispan.cdi.embedded module in WildFly which uses org.infinispan:infinispan-cdi-embedded-jakarta do I guess those artefacts exist. Nott sure what you are trying to acheive

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/infinispan/using-infinispan-with-wildfly-8/) and [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276133) we're not supposed to use the internal infinispan for applications. Instead we are relegated  to use it like [this](https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/integrating/integrating.html). However that doesn't seem fully updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since WildFly 28.0.0.Final there is no need to add the Infinispan modules since they are already integrated and available for usage in the main WildFly distribution - CDI, Query, Counters and Locks (of course without JCache).

Comment: There have been infinispan-modules in wildfly since forever. However it has been for internal usage only and instead you're supposed to use external modules. Se comment on other answer. Is this no longer true? There still exists modules [here](https://infinispan.org/download/); however they use javax-libraries instead of jakarta.